# PHP __call method for REST HTTP Verbs

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3

I am writing a REST wrapper class which looks like:

```
class RestApi
{
      public function __call($method, $resource, $data = []){
           return $this->call($method, $resource, $data);
      }

      public function call($http_verb, $resource, $data = []){}
}
```

But when I try to run the following...

```
$ra = new RestApi();
$ra->post('api/book/index');
```

It throws following error...

> RestApi::__call() must take exactly 2 arguments

I want to get rid of duplication code so I have decided to use `__call` magic method for all four http verbs. Please suggest a way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message suggests, the `__call` magic method only takes 2 arguments: the name of the method that was requested, and an *array* of arguments that were passed. All this info can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods).

With that in mind, maybe modify your code to look more like this:

```
public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    return $this->call($method, $arguments[0], $arguments[1]);
}
```

Assuming you implement the actual API requests with [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (which may be a very big assumption), you could do something like this inside your `call()` method:

```
switch (strtoupper($http_verb)) {
    case 'GET':
        // Nothing special happens here, this is CURL's default behavior
        break;
    case 'POST':
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        break;
    case 'PUT':
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
        break;

    // Etc...
}
```

This is purely an example to demonstrate the conditional logic you can do with the `__call()` magic method. There are many [libraries and frameworks](https://packagist.org/search/?q=REST%20client) that create REST wrappers like what you're trying to do. I suggest looking at one of those just as a learning experience, or maybe investigate a library like [Guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle).

Note: Of course, with an optional second argument (like what you have above), it would be smart to do some checks to see if `$arguments[1]`, etc. exist before blindly passing them along. Otherwise you'll get something like `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1`.

**UPDATE**

Regarding my last paragraph, @JayTaph had a good suggestion. A concise way to do this (one line, with no extra checks necessary) would be to use the following:

```
public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    return this->call($method, array_shift($arguments), $arguments);
}
```

If only one argument gets passed, after the first element gets shifted off with `array_shift()`, `$arguments` will be an empty array, which avoids the `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset` error I mentioned above.

Comment: Why not `$this->call($method, array_shift($arguments), $arguments);`

Comment: what if i use `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: @JayTaph Seems good to me, assuming the method signature stays the same. I updated my answer.

Comment: @seoppc It seems like you're on the right track with `__call()`, so you probably don't need to switch to `call_user_func_array()`. Are you looking for suggestions for what to put inside the actual `call()` function? If so, I can update my answer.

Comment: yes please. this will give me an idea to write proper code. Thanks

Comment: @seoppc Please see my updated answer. This is the best I can do without writing all the code for you. I hope that helps.